# Entity Framework 4.1 one to one relationship nullable

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Hello everybody again,

I need some help in this logic for EF 4.1
I have one table with data for a customer. I have also another table with a survey i need to compile when needed.
So initally i could insert a new customer and after some days I'll fill the survey form. Then the relationship MUST be one-to-one and optional (just because this survey could never be compiled for a customer).

I digged in some examples online but i'm really stuck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it mean that survey can exist without customer? What do you mean by optional?

Comment: I'm sorry i was not clear. The customer can exists without survery. This must be a one to one relationship where survey can be optional. Thank you

Comment: I forgot to mention that must have referential integrity on it

Answer (score 4):

Simply define your entities like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
}

public class Survey
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't like data annotations remove them and place this into `OnModelCreating` in your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Survey)
            .WithRequired(s => s.Customer);
```

Comment: Or you can create a separate mapping class that inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>

Comment: Finally got around to upgrading from 4.0 CTP5 to 4.2 ... spent hours tracking down a change to a 1 to 0..1 relationship...the .WithRequired(s => s.Customer) changed